# Run Function until true is returned OR 15 seconds has passed

Tags: vb.net

I have a method that needs to rerun until it either returns True or a set time period has passed. Would a cancellation token be the way to do this? A stopwatch? A timer?

```
    Do While partReady = False
        partReady = readTag(part, "_IO_EM_DI_04")
    Loop
```

Runs it until I get true returned but I need this to cancel and throw and exception or exit the loop after a given time period.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Stopwatch`:

```
    Dim sw As New Stopwatch
    sw.Start()

    Do While partReady = False
        partReady = readTag(part, "_IO_EM_DI_04")
        If sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds >= 15 Then
            Exit Do
        End If
    Loop
```

Comment: Well that was simple. I'll give this a shot and mark you off as answer if it's all good. Thanks man.

Comment: This might fail if, for example, the `TotalSeconds` value skips from say, 14 to 16.  That could happen if the `readTag` method takes an unexpected amount of time to complete.  It would be better to check for `TotalSeconds >= 15` to handle that condition.  I also just realized that `TotalSeconds` is a `Double`.  It may not be exactly 15 when you check it.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway I fixed, Thanks.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway this actually did happen so you were right on the money

Answer (score 0):

I would use a Timer here, where the contents of the loop from your question are moved to the Timer's `Elapsed` event. This will allow you to tune CPU use based on how often the timer ticks and help keep the loop from running away with your CPU core.